# PHP File Delete Issue?

Tags: php, html, delete-file

I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action='delete.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <div class = '.table'>
            <?php
            $dir = '../uploads/store/';
            $newdir = ereg_replace('\.','',$dir);

            if (is_dir($dir)) {
               if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
                  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                     if (!preg_match('/^(\.(htaccess|\.)?|index\.html)/',$file)) {
                        echo "<tr><td><font color = 'white'><a href='$newdir$file'>$file</a></font></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='submit' value ='Delete'></td></tr>";
                        echo "<input align='right' type='hidden' value='$file' name='file'>";
                     }
                  }
                  closedir($dh);
               }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </table>
</form>
```

Which links to the following PHP script:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $dir = '../uploads/store/';
    $file = $dir . $file;

    opendir($dir);

    if(unlink($file)) {
        echo "File sucessfully deleted";
        $_SESSION['username'] = 'guitarman0831';
        header('Refresh: 2;url=http://www.ohjustthatguy.com/uploads/uploads.html');
    } else {
        echo "Error: File could not be deleted";
        $_SESSION['username'] = 'guitarman0831';
        header('Refresh: 2;url=http://www.ohjustthatguy.com/uploads/uploads.html');
    }

?>
```

However, when the Delete button is pressed in the HTML form, the item above the one intended to delete is deleted.

Hope this makes sense.

NOTE: I'm not going for security with these scripts, I'm going to work on that later. It's only me using this service right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML form needs to have the various submit buttons pass the value for `$file` instead of using hidden fields.

The problem is that *all* of the hidden fields are POSTed to delete.php when you submit the form. Then, since you haven't used the PHP-friendly HTML array variable syntax, PHP uses only the last of these to set the value of `$_POST['file']`. If you do a `var_dump` of `$_POST` in `delete.php`, you will see what the POSTed input is.

The easiest thing to do, with your current markup, is just to have each submit button be named `file` and pass $file as its `value`. i.e. you could do:

```
<button name="file" value="example.txt" type="submit">Delete</button>
```

Alternately, you could use radio buttons or some other markup.

Comment: p.s. The script as written is insecure. It's subject to directory traversal attack, CSRF ... always validate your inputs! [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) is your friend.

Comment: Doesn't work, error: "Warning: unlink(../uploads/store/) [function.unlink]: Is a directory "